# Tengo un problema con el comando self en sublime text 3

Tags: python

Miren cuando escribo un me funciona pero cuando lo saco del () me sale en rojo y sospecho que eso es lo que hace que no me funcionen los proyectos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando en Python (sublime text 3)

Comment: No se entiende nada.

Comment: Considerá reformular tu pregunta: en verdad no se entiende cuál es realmente el problema que tenés.